# Querying a CLOB column containing an XML-message

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, clob

I'm trying to datamine a table. The table contains a column where xml-messages are stored, using the CLOB datatype. The XML-message has the following structure:

```
<t:MsgNameXML typeInfo="source" xsi:schemaLocation="http://example/location FileName.xsd" xmlns:t="http://url/of/custom/namespace" xmlns:"http://url/of/default/namespace"      >
    <t:info1>data1</t:info1>
    <t:info2>data2</t:info2>
    <t:Section>
        <t:SubSection>
            <t:SubSubSection>
                <t:variable1>data3</t:variable1>
                <t:variable2>data4</t:variable2>
            </t:SubSubSection>
        </t:SubSection>
    </t:Section>
    <t:Section>
        <t:SubSection>
            <t:SubSubSection>
                <t:variable1>data5</t:variable1>
                <t:variable2>data6</t:variable2>
            </t:SubSubSection>
        </t:SubSection>
    </t:Section>
</t:MsgNameXML>
```

So, at least for me, the main difficulties are the namespaces and the fact that there a multiple nodes.

I hope to get the following output (for the record containing the above XML):

```
INFO1   INFO2   VARIABLE1   VARIABLE2
-------------------------------------
data1   data2   data3       data4
data1   data2   data5       data6
```

I've constructed the following query to try to extract "variable1" (Oracle database, so PL SQL, I guess):

```
select 
extractvalue(xmltype(CLOB_COLUMN_NAME),
'/t:MsgNameXML/t:Section/t:SubSection/t:SubSubSection/t:variable1',
'xmlns:t="xmlns:t="http://url/of/custom/namespace" xmlns:"http://url/of/default/namespace"')

from 
TABLE_NAME,
TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(CLOB_COLUMN_NAME, '/t:MsgNameXML/t:Section/t:SubSection/t:SubSubSection/t:variable1')))
```

This unfortunately produces the following error message:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 9 Column: 33
```

(Line 9, column 33, refers to where CLOB_COLUMN_NAME is located after the EXTRACT-function in the from-clause).

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, and how I could correct this?

In addition, I'd need to expand this query to extract more values from the XML-message, rather than just the "variable1" (see desired result above). Any help on that would be much appreciated as well.

Thank you for your help,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate cause of your ORA-00932 is that you're trying to extract directly from a CLOB; you're converting on one place already, but this:

```
TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(CLOB_COLUMN_NAME, ... )))
```

... would need to be:

```
TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(XMLType(CLOB_COLUMN_NAME), ... )))
```

But the namespace still isn't recognised in that clause, and you'd get ORA-31011 if you only change that. You can get something out by including the namespace in the `EXTRACT` call as well, and correcting the typo in that:

```
select extractvalue(column_value, '/t:variable1',
  'xmlns:t="http://url/of/custom/namespace" xmlns:"http://url/of/default/namespace"')
  as variable1
from 
TABLE_NAME,
TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(XMLType(CLOB_COLUMN_NAME),
  '/t:MsgNameXML/t:Section/t:SubSection/t:SubSubSection/t:variable1',
  'xmlns:t="http://url/of/custom/namespace" xmlns:"http://url/of/default/namespace"')));

VARIABLE1
----------
data3      
data5
```

Or both variables at once by shifting the extract back a level:

```
select extractvalue(column_value, 't:SubSubSection/t:variable1',
  'xmlns:t="http://url/of/custom/namespace" xmlns:"http://url/of/default/namespace"')
  as variable1,
  extractvalue(column_value, 't:SubSubSection/t:variable2',
  'xmlns:t="http://url/of/custom/namespace" xmlns:"http://url/of/default/namespace"')
  as variable2
from 
TABLE_NAME,
TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(XMLType(CLOB_COLUMN_NAME),
  '/t:MsgNameXML/t:Section/t:SubSection/t:SubSubSection',
  'xmlns:t="http://url/of/custom/namespace" xmlns:"http://url/of/default/namespace"')));

VARIABLE1  VARIABLE2
---------- ----------
data3      data4      
data5      data6
```

Including the info values as well is going to make it more complicated and repetitive:

```
select extractvalue(XMLType(CLOB_COLUMN_NAME), 't:MsgNameXML/t:info1',
  'xmlns:t="http://url/of/custom/namespace" xmlns:"http://url/of/default/namespace"')
  as info1,
  extractvalue(XMLType(CLOB_COLUMN_NAME), 't:MsgNameXML/t:info2',
  'xmlns:t="http://url/of/custom/namespace" xmlns:"http://url/of/default/namespace"')
  as info2,
  extractvalue(column_value, 't:SubSubSection/t:variable1',
  'xmlns:t="http://url/of/custom/namespace" xmlns:"http://url/of/default/namespace"')
  as variable1,
  extractvalue(column_value, 't:SubSubSection/t:variable2',
  'xmlns:t="http://url/of/custom/namespace" xmlns:"http://url/of/default/namespace"')
  as variable2
from 
TABLE_NAME,
TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(XMLType(CLOB_COLUMN_NAME),
  '/t:MsgNameXML/t:Section/t:SubSection/t:SubSubSection',
  'xmlns:t="http://url/of/custom/namespace" xmlns:"http://url/of/default/namespace"')));

INFO1      INFO2      VARIABLE1  VARIABLE2
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
data1      data2      data3      data4      
data1      data2      data5      data6
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2bdbb/2) of this approach.

---

You can use [XQuery and XMLTable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm) instead of the older extract syntax:

```
select info1, info2, variable1, variable2
from table_name,
  xmltable('declare namespace t = "http://url/of/custom/namespace"; (: :)
    for $i in /t:MsgNameXML
      let $info1 := $i/t:info1,
        $info2 := $i/t:info2
      for $j in $i/t:Section/t:SubSection/t:SubSubSection
        let $variable1 := $j/t:variable1,
          $variable2 := $j/t:variable2
      return <tmp>
          <info1>{$info1}</info1>
          <info2>{$info2}</info2>
          <variable1>{$variable1}</variable1>
          <variable2>{$variable2}</variable2>
        </tmp>'
passing xmltype(CLOB_COLUMN_NAME)
columns
  info1     char(10) path '/tmp/info1',
  info2     char(10) path '/tmp/info2',
  variable1 char(10) path '/tmp/variable1',
  variable2 char(10) path '/tmp/variable2'
);

INFO1      INFO2      VARIABLE1  VARIABLE2
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
data1      data2      data3      data4      
data1      data2      data5      data6
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2bdbb/1).

I had to tweak the CLOB value a little to make it valid; changing `xsi=` to `xmlns:xsi=` and setting a dummy name for the default namespace, `xmlns:x="http://url/of/default/namespace"`. I think that was all...

XQuery is a "functional language based on sequences", and this uses ["FLOWR" expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB5092). Specifically two `for` loops to iterate over the structure, and `let` expressions to assign the namespace variables to local variables which are then returned in a simpler XML structure, from which the columns can be extracted via their new paths. (You don't seem to be able to use namespaces directly in the `path` strings).

It should be fairly easy to expand this to get more values out of your message - more `let` expressions, and more matching `path` extractions.

But I'm really just scratching the surface of this stuff myself, so there may be simpler/better/faster ways to do this; hopefully a starting point for an XQuery approach, anyway.

Comment: Alex, sorry for taking so long to respond to you.
It took me forever to get your solution (using XQuery en XMLTable functions) to work, because of some silly mistake I kept on missing. It finally caught my eye today though, and now it works like a charm. So thank you very much!